# How can I fix "not found: /sbin/iptables" in Debian 11

Tags: debian, iptables

I am trying to do a lab work on a proxy server for study. I should warn you right away that I do not know anything about this subject, but I need help. I did everything according to the instructions provided by the teacher. So, to the crux of the matter:

I have an `iptables.sh file` which looks like this:

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
    IPTABLES=' /sbin/iptables'
    EXTIF='enp0s3'
    INTIF1='enp0s8'
    /bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    $IPTABLES -F
    $IPTABLES -t nat -F
    $IPTABLES -t mangle -F
    $IPTABLES -X
    $IPTABLES -t nat -X
    $IPTABLES -t mangle -X
    $IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
    $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INTIF1 -o $EXTIF -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.20.2.0/24 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s 10.20.2.0/24 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    
    #iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    #iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    #iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    #iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
    
    $IPTABLES -A INPUT --protocol tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
    $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
    $IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m state --state NEW,INVALID -j DROP
    #$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -m state --state NEW,INVALID -j DROP
```

When I run the following command in the virtual machine as root `sh iptables.sh`, I get the following:

[image]

not found: /sbin/iptables

What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your file has Windows-style line terminator characters.

Please test with the command `file iptables.sh`.

The output will be similar to:

```
iptables.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

If the `with CRLF line terminators` is there, the script must be converted to use Unix-style line terminators:

```
fromdos iptables.sh   # in package "tofrodos"
```

or

```
dos2unix iptables.sh   # in package "dos2unix"
```

If there are still errors after that, check the variable assignment on the 3rd line:

```
IPTABLES=' /sbin/iptables'
```

If the space character before `/sbin` is an ALT-space or some other not-really-space character, it might cause some of the errors. The space is unnecessary, so just remove it:

```
IPTABLES='/sbin/iptables'
```